# Why does JSON.parse('{"key" : "value"}') do just fine but JSON.parse('{key : "value"}') doesn't?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

From the node REPL:

```
> JSON.parse('{"key" : "value"}')
{ key: 'value' }
> JSON.parse('{key : "value"}')
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Object.parse (native)
    at [object Context]:1:6
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:171:22)
        at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty_posix.js:307:10)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All keys in JSON are strings, and all strings are delimited by double quotes.

JavaScript allows you to use different characters to delimit strings, and it allows you to use identifiers as keys in an object literal — but JSON is not JavaScript.

Comment: +1. also, if you want to check if something is valid json, you can use a validator such as http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

JSON expects both keys and values to be strings.

http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Values don't have to be strings actually. They can be booleans, numbers and others, but keys have to be strings.

Answer (score 0):

Because your second example isn't JSON.